# QT Creator: How to generate the library and testing executable for a custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, dll, qt-creator

There is the following files:

```
MyWidget
   |- MyWidget.cpp
   |- MyWidget.hpp
   |- MyWidget_UnitTest.cpp
```

I would like to generate at once following files:

1. MyWidget.dll (or equivalent for non windows OS)
2. MyWidget_UnitTest.exe (or equivalent for non windows OS)

So it is easy to test the widget for bugs, but also to have the result inside further widgets or projects.

I tried to manipulate the .pro file, but with no success:

```
# ONLY TESTING UNIT
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = MyWidget_UnitTest
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES +=\
    MyWidget.cpp \
    MyWidget_UnitTest.cpp
HEADERS  += \
    MyWidget.hpp
CONFIG += c++11 -Wall

#ONLY LIB
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = MyWidget_UnitTest
TEMPLATE = lib
SOURCES +=\
    MyWidget.cpp \
    MyWidget_UnitTest.cpp
HEADERS  += \
    MyWidget.hpp
CONFIG += c++11 -Wall
CONFIG += dll
```

I am unable to merge both into a single project.

Possibly more result could be added: static vs dynamic lib, etc.

Comment: This exactly what Internal Library is for - see http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html. It is a subproject that creates the library, and is a dependency of your main project (the exe).

Comment: As I understand this document, it explain how to include libraries, not how to generate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SUBDIRS project organization.

```
project_dir/
  src/
    your_dll/
      ... sources, headers ...
      your_dll.pro
    your_exe/
      ... sources, headers ...
      your_exe.pro
  project_dir.pro
```

**project_dir.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += src/your_dll
SUBDIRS += src/your_exe

your_exe.depends = your_dll
```

**your_exe.pro**

```
TARGET = your_exe
TEMPLATE = app
QT += widgets
LIBS += -L$${YOUR_DLL_PATH} -lyour_dll

etc...
```

**your_dll.pro**

```
TARGET = your_dll
TEMPLATE = lib
QT += widgets

etc...
```

Now when you build, the DLL and EXE will be built, and the EXE will be linked to the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Use different `CONFIG` flags:

```
QT += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
SOURCES +=MyWidget.cpp
HEADERS += MyWidget.hpp
CONFIG += c++11 -Wall

testmode {
    # ONLY TESTING UNIT
    TARGET = MyWidget_UnitTest
    SOURCES += MyWidget_UnitTest.cpp
    TEMPLATE = app
}

libmode {
    #ONLY LIB
    TARGET = MyWidget
    TEMPLATE = lib
    CONFIG += dll
}
```

To build both:

```
qmake "CONFIG+=libmode"
make
qmake "CONFIG+=testmode"
make
```

Comment: And to build both together?

Comment: Call `qmake` twice to get both.